# Show Hide closest element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/KevinOrin/xycCx/1/

```
jQuery('.happening-main-text .readmore').click(function() {                  
    jQuery('.divmore').toggle('slow');       
    return false;                                       
});
```

I am trying to get each link to show/hide only the one clicked. How can I modify the JS to do so. I tried `('.happening-main-text').closest('divmore')` and that did not work either.

```
<div class="happening-main-text">
    <p>part of text goes here part of text <a href="#" class="readmore">show/hide</a>

    </p>
    <div class="divmore">
        <p>more test from hidden1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="happening-main-text">
    <p>part of text goes here part of text <a href="#" class="readmore">show/hide</a>

    </p>
    <div class="divmore">
        <p>more test from hidden</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="happening-main-text">
    <p>part of text goes here part of text <a href="#" class="readmore">show/hide</a>

    </p>
    <div class="divmore">
        <p>more test from hidden2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Closest how? Closest sibling? Descendant? Ancestor? How can anyone tell you how to select a DOM element that we can't see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep your current format for HTML the following code should work

```
jQuery('.happening-main-text .readmore').click(function() {                  
    jQuery(this).parent().next().toggle('slow');       
    return false;                                       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the DOM in your fiddle, this could be a way to solve it:

```
jQuery('.happening-main-text .readmore').click(function() {                  
    jQuery(this).parent().next().toggle('slow');
    return false;
}
```

Have a look at [$.next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [$.parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) in the docs. Also, you might notice that the animation is "jumpy", this is because of the margin on `p` ([related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/991484/137972)). Removing the margin will solve this. For instance:

```
p { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: Actually, this is better than mine :).

Answer (score 0):

Kevin, try to go this way:

```
$('.happening-main-text').each(function() {
    $divmore = $(this).find(".divmore");
    $readmore = $(this).find(".readmore");
    $readmore.bind("click", {target: $divmore}, function(e) {
        e.data.target.toggle();
    });
});
```

You need to pass a different target to each click callback because of the structure of your html. Refactoring a bit the DOM would allow you to use $().siblings or other simpler solutions.
Anyway, you can take a look at a working version of your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xycCx/6/

Answer (score 0):

The solution follows (http://jsfiddle.net/4nJWf/):

*Note*: bug fix in your original HTML

**HTML**

```
<div class="happening-main-text">
    <p>part of text goes here part of text <a href="#" class="readmore">show/hide</a>
    </p>
    <div class="divmore">
        <p>more test from hidden1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="happening-main-text">
    <p>part of text goes here part of text <a href="#" class="readmore">show/hide</a>
    </p>
    <div class="divmore")">
        <p>more test from hidden</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="happening-main-text">
    <p>part of text goes here part of text <a href="#" class="readmore">show/hide</a>
    </p>
    <div class="divmore">
        <p>more test from hidden2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('.happening-main-text .readmore').click(function() {                  
    $(this).parents('.happening-main-text').children('.divmore').toggle('slow');       
    return false;                                       
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already been answered but it looks like the hidden text in the class `divmore` is not shown in the solution but instead it hides the rest of the `happening-main-text` class.

It should only toggle the `.divmore` class immediate to the clicked `<a>` like the one below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".readmore").click(function(){
     $(this).parent("p").siblings("div").toggle("slow");        
  });
```

});

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdy_dot/uvUgr/1/)